# extracting functionality info of a user defined function

Tags: r

```
mysum <- function(x,y){
  #this is my sum function and it is used for..
  #john's updated version, x in int, y in double.
  k <- sum(x,y)
  return(k)
}
```

say I have a `mysum` function and wanted to see the functionality and some basic info, how do one extract the function's info?

Instead of looking into the script directly, would like to have something similar like `?mysum` or `mysum.info` that can print out that two line of comment/info from my console. Thanks.

Comment: R does not have a way of calling the docstring like in python. All the comments in R are ignored completely and thus not callable.

Comment: Build a package and use roxygen2. Many tutorials are available.

Comment: You should make a package, but if you want something simpler you can add an attribute to the function: `attr (mysum, "info") <- "Function info"`. The function will work the same and you can consult the attribute at any time.